# Junit tests start failing after adding @ComponentScan in the Spring boot application class file

Tags: spring-boot, junit

I am using Spring boot version 2.3.3.Release
Junit platform launcher 1.5.2

If I add `@ComponentScan` under `@SpringBootApplication`, the tests fail with the error :-

`Caused by org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException at RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:367`

My tests have the config like :-

```
@ExtendsWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = Abcd.class)
```

And i use :-
`@MockBean` for service layer and
`@Autowired` for MockMvc bean

`EDIT 1:`
I added the ComponentScan to include an external library. The jar is in a lib folder and i use gradle compile filetree to include it.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal reproducible example, otherwise this is rather complicated to answer

Comment: Hi Eugene, that's just it .. all the tests, code etc are in the same package.. it's when i add the componentscan annotation to include a new package, the test start failing

Comment: I will repeat: provide a simple minimal example we can run and reproduce the problem, if you want to be helped.

Comment: Sure, i'll paste screenshots ..

Comment: _so that we can run_ != _screenshots_. I will stop commenting

Comment: :D okok .. i will paste the code and my build as well